# synonym state name match in Elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I am using elastic search for matching the location to the elastic search index.

sample of Elastic search index data

```
{
"_index": "reference_2",
"_type": "geonames",
"_id": "AUn2LNJlZ8pWP0iSxZYS",
"_version": 1,
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
    "geoNameId": "7509382",
    "lat": "34.64274",
    "longi": "64.51122",
    "timeZoneId": "Asia/Kabul",
    "countryCode": "AF",
    "state": "Tamil nadu",
    "timezone": "AFT",
    "stateCode": "09",
    "alterCityName": [
        chennai
    ],
    "cityName": "chennai",
    "population": "0",
    "countryName": "India"
},
"sort": [
    1,
    "geonames",
    "reference_2"
]
}
```

User can write the state as "tamilnadu" or tamil nadu, I want the program or the query to understand that tamilnadu is same as tamil nadu. 
can any one help me how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to define a synonym file containing all the synonyms you want to use. Provide the specific mapping to your fields to use that particular synonym file.

for example, you synonym file will contain something like,

```
tamil nadu,tamilnadu,tn => tamilnadu
andhra pradesh,andra,andrhrapradesh,ap => andhrapradesh
```

Give the path pf the synonym file to a custom analysis and use it for your field.

```
 "filter": {
            "custom_state": {
                "type" : "synonym",
                "synonyms_path" : "<path to synonym file>"
            },
   .....

   "analyzer": {
            "states": {
                "type":         "custom",
                "filter": [ "lowercase", "custom_state"]
            },
   .......
   "properties" : {
        "STATE" : {"type" : "string", "analyzer": "states"},
    ........
```

The advantage of using a separate synonym file is that you can extend/include more values later also easily.